# How can I randomly replace only a few words (not all) in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I replace, say, 250 out of 1000 words in Microsoft Word?

For example, 'happy' is written about 1000 times in my document. I want to replace only 250 of them with the word 'joy'.

So is there a function or way to do that at once in Microsoft Word?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but can I ask why?

Comment: So you want some chance for "I am happy to announce" to become "I am joy to announce" ?  Not useful for making your paper have more word variation but would be useful for an ESL test! That being said I have no idea if word allows custom functions like excel does, but such a thing would be trivial in python, r, or most programming languages for that matter.

Comment: @eps When I was a kid, we went to McDonalds I ate my first joy Meal on my birthday. I was very joy. Then we sang: joy birthday to you! joy birthday to you! joy birthday, dear immibis! joy birthday to you! Then my aunt said, because it was close to Christmas, "joy holidays"! but I corrected her and told her she was being too politically correct, and it should be "merry Christmas and a joy New Year!"

Comment: This is an uncommon kind of question, but it [seems to be on-topic](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/a-broad-guideline-for-questions-about-writing-specific-software/1102#1102). But what about [extra tags](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1802/the-tools-tag-and-its-subsidiaries)?

Comment: What version of Microsoft Word and on what platform?

Comment: Replacing happi*ness* with joy would work. Happy's an adjective, though, and joy is a noun. Are you looking for joy*ful*?

Comment: People are taking this question far too literally I think.  My guess is we're looking at a Ren & Stimpy reference.  (I don't think you're joy enough.  I'll *teach* you to be joy...)  I assume those were just example words.

Comment: It would be easy enough to write a VBA macro to automate this, but there is no built-in feature for probabilistic word replacement.

Comment: Even assuming we're replacing with the correct part of speech (happy to joyful, or happiness to joy, say), I'm struggling to think of a circumstance in which getting the computer to randomly replace some of them is the right thing to do. That's just not how writing works... (Unless the very concept of this piece is the computerisation aspect, in which case I suspect you'd need something more sophisticated than Word to be competitive in the current market.)

Answer (score 16):

The quickest way is to do a "Find" (Ctrl+F) and cycle through each individual instance and select replace when you wish to replace the instance with "Joy".

Comment: @User999 I agree. My editor kept picking words I overused, and this gives you the review of all of them, so you decide which to keep and which to dump, one at a time (repetitive, but accurate). But it's not going to be random. You'll need to choose.

Comment: I guess you could flip a coin for each of them. :)

Comment: When you get down too it, at this stage, it might be that a random number a spaced far enough apart that they would be unremarkable, but there are clusters where you really need to break out a thesurus.  Don't just replace 1/4 of the total words with another synonym.

Comment: This. You don't want to ramdomply replace some of them, but the search highlights them ALL so you see where they cluster and then you can replace (manually) some of them there

Comment: This is a good answer, partly because it's non-technical (much as I love programmatically editing Word docs, cough cough), and partly because it preserves the human factor needed to not make this an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 4):

This solution will probably be more programming intensive than what you are looking for but I'll put in out there is case it is of use to someone.  MS Word just stores a document as a zip file with a .docx extension.  You can unzip it with standard utilities.  The zip file contains a number of xml files as well as other files that hold formatting information.  The body of the document is stored in a file called document.xml.  Since this is a text file it is possible to write an application to do a search and replace on only a specific number of matches and then re-zip the file and rename it with a .docx extension.  As was mentioned earlier this could also be also be done with one of the Visual Basic/C languages using [VSTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) but there may be more of a learning curve if you haven't used it before.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method directly in Word for replacing every 3rd, then every 5th occurrence of "happy" with "joy'. After you record one macro (to make an average of 25% swaps), you run a second macro once that runs the first one to document end:

1. **Record** a macro, naming it **MacroJoy1** (View / Macros / Run Macro).
   Use Ctl-H (not -F) to find the next "happy."
   Click "Find Next".
   Click "Find Next". Replace "happy" with "joy".

Click "Find Next".
Click "Find Next".
Click "Find Next".
Click "Find Next".
Click "Find Next". Replace "happy" with "joy".
**Stop** Recording.

2. **Record** **MacroJoy2**, which runs MacroJoy1 125 times. Number can be higher.
   **Stop** recording.
3. Run **MacroJoy2**!

Comment: You could change this into instructions for incorporating the RND function linked in my answer, for randomization of how many times a macro / function repeats...

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a pain, but as far as I know there is no such function native to MS Word. Besides that, you'll probably be best off using CTRL+F and reviewing each case individually for context, rhythm, etc. before making changes -- indiscriminate machine replacement will probably make more problems than it solves.

Comment: Perhaps it calls for some kind of script? [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm afraid I wouldn't know. Maybe!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, like other people are saying, making a VBA Macro is the way to go:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c

---

Something like using the [Find function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Find), then randomly, with the [RND function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function), going some number of spaces ahead, and then replacing the selection with the word you want.

Answer (score 0):

Only manually, or by subjecting your Word document to a programming language… which for any single instance will almost certainly be at least as difficult.

To the extent you can re-use it the idea becomes more efficient, though no more easy.

Word itself has no conception of how to replace X out of Y words.

Comment: The programming language of choice to subject it to is certainly the MSOffice built-in VBA. No additional program required, access to all Word features. It's difficult the first time, perhaps; but going through 1000 find locations in a Word document is a serious pain.

Answer (score 0):

Not random, but no special tools required. To replace every fourth occurrence (case sensitive):

- Find and Replace > Replace
- Use wildcards = checked
- Find: `(<happy>*)(<happy>*)(<happy>*)<happy>`
- Replace: `\1\2\3joy`
- Replace All

With (some) case insensitivity:

- Find and Replace > Replace
- Use wildcards = checked
- Find: `(<[Hh]appy>*)(<[Hh]appy>*)(<[Hh]appy>*)<[Hh]appy>`
- Replace: `\1\2\3JOY`
- Replace All
- Match case = checked
- Find: `JOY`
- Replace: (`joy`|`Joy`, as required)

(The repeat function (`{3}`, `{1,3}`) doesn't like wildcards (`*`), so multifind statements like this have to be manually created.)

This can be made pseudorandom by replacing multiple times and with different occurrences (e.g. every 7th, then every 5th). The Find and Replace input boxes are limited to 256 characters, so there's only so many that can be done in one go (19 in this case). But any more than every 7th results in the error '*The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is too complex*':

- `(<[Hh]appy>*)(<[Hh]appy>*)(<[Hh]appy>*)(<[Hh]appy>*)(<[Hh]appy>*)(<[Hh]appy>*)<[Hh]appy>`
- `\1\2\3\4\5\6JOY`